# Bluetooth interface control in C code ( Linux OS )

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

Normally I can control the interface through the command

```
 hciconfig hcix up/down
```

Can I do this by using c code ?

Is there sample code I can refer to ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the c code for hciconfig itself. Just download the [BlueZ source](http://www.bluez.org/) and open tools/hciconfig.c and use the following functions:-

```
static void cmd_up(int ctl, int hdev, char *opt)
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
static void cmd_down(int ctl, int hdev, char *opt) 
{
    ... 
}
```